# Vue-js and different layouts

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

how would one layout the router-views, if you have, lets say 3 different layout to use for you app (e.g. layout for customers, layout for employer and admin-interface).

At the moment i implemented the customer "view" like:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HeaderBar/>
    <Navigation></Navigation>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

inside the App.vue file. I could use something like:

```
<div id="app">
    <router-view name="header">
      <HeaderBar/>
      <Navigation></Navigation>
    </router-view>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

and load different headers for those "subroutes" but this seem's to be odd.
Also what, if i'd like to use an other index.html?
I'm using webpack for this app.

Or would you suggest to create different apps for this?

Many thanks
rene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

Basically you change which component is being rendered depending on your route.

So it would probably be something like this:

```
<component v-bind:is="headerComponent"></component>
```

and then your app can contain `heeaderComponent` property in data object that has a default value and gets changed when you click on a route that should use different header. Rinse and repeat for the footer.

As for the last question, I think you should only use one app. As it is possible to do and everything is still connected. I'm not sure but I don't know how would you, if need be, communicate between different instances of Vue.